# Are empty macro arguments legal in C++11?

Tags: c++, macros, c++11

I sometimes deliberately omit macro arguments. For example, for a function-like macro like

```
#define MY_MACRO(A, B, C)  ...
```

I might call it as:

```
MY_MACRO(, bar, baz)
```

There are still technically 3 arguments; it's just that the first one is "empty". This question is not about variadic macros.

When I do this I get warnings from g++ when compiling with `-ansi` (aka `-std=c++98`), but not when I use `-std=c++0x`. Does this mean that empty macro args are legal in the new C++ standard?

That's the entirety of my question, but anticipating the "why would you want to?" response, here's an example. I like keeping .h files uncluttered by function bodies, but implementing simple accessors outside of the .h file is tedious. I therefore wrote the following macro:

```
#define IMPLEMENT_ACCESSORS(TEMPLATE_DECL, RETURN_TYPE, CLASS, FUNCTION, MEMBER) \
  TEMPLATE_DECL                                                         \
  inline RETURN_TYPE* CLASS::Mutable##FUNCTION() {                      \
    return &MEMBER;                                                     \
  }                                                                     \
                                                                        \
  TEMPLATE_DECL                                                         \
  inline const RETURN_TYPE& CLASS::FUNCTION() const {                   \
    return MEMBER;                                                      \
  }
```

This is how I would use it for a class template that contains an `int` called `int_`:

```
IMPLEMENT_ACCESSORS(template<typename T>, int, MyTemplate<T>, Int, int_)
```

For a non-template class, I don't need `template<typename T>`, so I omit that macro argument:

```
IMPLEMENT_ACCESORS(, int, MyClass, Int, int_)
```

Comment: Why not have simple have two difference macros with the same name. One taking one argument less

Comment: @parapura rajkumar: Same reason you don not want two functions that do the same things. If a piece of code is repeated than maintaining it becomes harder. Any fix has to applied to each copy.

Comment: FWIW I don't get any warnings with either gcc or g++ when expanding a macro with empty arguments, even with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -ansi`.  What's the exact warning you're getting?

Comment: @parapura: Because macros are not overloadable, you can only have one macro with a certain name.

Comment: SuperElectric, R. Martinho: I edited the question to reflect the fact that C++11 has been officially published.

Comment: I am wondering whether anyone can provide an example where `cpp` (whatever version, with whatever standard) complains about empty macro argument. Using empty macro args is very widespread and follorw the design logic (it is a *macro* language).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I understand correctly, empty macro argument is allowed since C99 and
C++0x(11).
C99 6.10.3/4 says:

> ... the number of arguments (including those arguments consisting of
>   no preprocessing tokens) shall equal the number of parameters ...

and C++ N3290 16.3/4 has the same statement, while C++03 16.3/10 mentions:

> ... any argument consists of no preprocessing tokens, the behavior is
>   undefined.

I think empty argument comes under the representation *arguments consisting of
no preprocessing tokens* above.
Also, 6.10.3 in Rationale for International Standard Programming Languages C rev. 5.10
 says:

> A new feature of C99: Function-like macro invocations may also now
>   have empty arguments, that is, an argument may consist of no
>   preprocessing tokens.

Comment: I'm searching for a use for empty argument lists, but all the websites only say they exist. Do you know of any examples?

Comment: @Shahbaz Here's an example: `#define JOIN(x,y,z) x##y##z`, then use as `JOIN(a,b,c); JOIN(a,b,); JOIN(a,,)` to get `abc; ab; a`.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. The relevant bit is 16.3/11

> The sequence of preprocessing tokens bounded by the outside-most
>   matching parentheses forms the list of arguments for the function-like
>   macro. The individual arguments within the list are separated by comma
>   preprocessing tokens.

There's no requirement that a single argument corresponds to precisely one token. In fact, the following section makes it clear that there can be more than one token per argument:

> Before being substituted, each argument’s preprocessing tokens are
>   completely macro replaced as if they formed the rest of the
>   preprocessing file

In your case, one argument happens to correspond to zero tokens. That doesn't cause any contradiction.

[edit]
This was changed by [N1566](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1566.htm) to bring C++11 in line with C99.

Comment: But did that part change between C++03 and C++11 or was it always there?

Comment: Definitely c++03 allowed (at least as implemented by gcc) empty macro args, I used them all the time.

Comment: @eudoxos: That's probably because GCC implemented C99 functionality even in C++ mode

Comment: @MSalters: eh nope. Those two lines `#define AA(a,b)` and `AA(,)` get happily crunched by `cpp -Werror -Wall -ansi` (which is, according to man page, the same as `C90`).

Comment: @eudoxos GCC chooses to treat a bunch of things that are undefined behavior in C89 and/or C++98, but defined by C99, as having their C99 semantics regardless of whether C99 support is explicitly turned on.  (Many of these were "undefined but all implementations do it this way" prior to C99, which merely codified practice.)

Answer (score 6):

<strike>When I do that I normally put a comment in place of the argument.</strike>

Place a macro that will be expanded to the empty string.

```
#define NOARG
...
MY_MACRO(/*Ignore this Param*/ NOARG, bar, baz)
```

PS. I got no warning with g++ with or without the -std=c++98 flag.

- g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3
- g++ (Apple Inc. build 5666) 4.2.1

Comment: That's actually the same. Per 2.2 Phases of translation, comments are replaced by one space in step 3, and macro's are replaced in step 4.

Comment: Using your trick, the warning is still present (used `clang -pedantic -std=c++98`), due to the reason MSalters explained. A better way to avoid the warning is to use a dummy macro that expands to nothing, e.g. `#define NOARG` then you can use `MY_MACRO(NOARG, bar, baz)`.