# Invoking macros with one argument

Tags: c++, c, macros

recently I was browsing SO and I came across [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537964/visual-c-equivalent-of-gccs-attribute-packed), where Sam Jansen is declaring a macro `PACKED_STRUCT(name)`, but in code he is using it once with no arguments and once with the name argument supplied.

I tried to compile a similar sample progam with GCC 4.6.1 and I was surprised it compiled fine with no warnings at all (I was using `-std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` command line switches).
However when I tried to make two argument macro and call it with less than two arguments, it did not work.

So my question is if this is a bug in GCC, or it is a feature of GCC, or it is defined somewhere in the standard, that it has to work like this?

According to [this page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Arguments.html) in GCC's documentation, this should not be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read that page of GCC's documentation again; it's making a distinction between *empty* arguments and *missing* arguments.  Given

```
#define ONE(x)    one(x)
#define TWO(x,y)  two(x,y)
```

all of these are perfectly fine as far as the preprocessor is concerned (expansion in comment):

```
ONE(1)    /* one(1)   */
ONE()     /* one()    */
TWO(1,2)  /* two(1,2) */
TWO(1,)   /* two(1,)  */
TWO(,2)   /* two(,2)  */
TWO(,)    /* two(,)   */
```

but this is not okay:

```
TWO()     /* error: macro "TWO" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given */
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems you are right. Additionally I found [a similar SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666344/are-empty-macro-arguments-legal-in-c11), where the accepted answer states that empty macro arguments should be legal even with C99 standard