# macro argument deduction seems incorrect with zero arguments?

Tags: c

```
# define CALL(a, b) test(a, b)

CALL();
```

Compiling the above with `gcc -E 0.c` fails with:

```
error: macro "CALL" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
```

But I haven't given it any arguments, where is the first argument coming from?

Similarly this snippet doesn't cause preprocessor errors which is strange:

```
# define CALL(a) test(a)

CALL();
```

Comment: What is `test` defined as?

Comment: @Lundin as nothing, this is just testing the preprocessor.

Comment: This [gcc C Preprocessor](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~prabal/teaching/eecs373-f11/readings/Preprocessor.pdf) document by Stallman/Weinberg says "The number of arguments you give must match the number of parameters in the macro definition." on page 16.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/7666344/10622916 "A new feature of C99: Function-like macro invocations may also now have empty arguments, that is, an argument may consist of no preprocessing tokens."

Comment: @Bodo right but i'm asking why is it reporting "1" argument is passed where i have passed nothing.

Comment: A macro call like `XXX()` does have *one* argument - but it's a 'nothing' value. A macro call with **no argument** is one without the `()`.

Comment: Dan, what happens with `CALL(42);`?

Comment: An empty argument is an argument. `# define CALL(a,b) test(a,b)` `CALL(,);` --> `test(,);`

Comment: I see so `CALL()` has 1 empty argument and `CALL(,)` has 2.

Comment: I can't really post it as an answer without **blatant** plagiarism, but see [this blog](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/detect-empty-macro-arguments/).

Comment: I'm not buying anything said in the duplicate. I can't find the normative text in the standard anywhere. If this was a new feature of C99, it was very sneakily hidden. The identifier-list(opt) part of the formal grammar was there in C90 too. And it doesn't seem to allow an empty argument.

Comment: All I can find is C17 6.10.3/4 which seems to contradict that "empty arguments is a new C99 feature". This is all very badly written, to the point where a DR would be called for in my opinion. Someone wrote a DR back in 1995 [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/dr_153.html) which seems to be the origin of the supposed change... which I can't find documented anywhere in normative text.

Comment: @Lundin (and others). As I said, I'm reluctant to post a 'copy' of the blog I linked as an answer but I do feel this question is good one and worthy of a proper answer. Would a Community Wiki summarizing the comments be a good idea, in your opinion?

Comment: @AdrianMole That blog doesn't quote any normative part of the standard so I don't see how it is relevant. The C99 preface and rationale say "empty argument list is a new feature" but nothing in normative text seems to back that up.

Comment: I think the key to the defect is that the standard says "including those arguments consisting of no preprocessing tokens". But the argument list is formally defined as an identifier-list, where an identifier cannot be left empty. And if you leave out the optional identifier-list, then nothing describes what will happen, anywhere. The syntax contradicts the rest of the text.

Comment: Again, not *directly* relevant, but [this **C++** draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) has (19.3.4): *If the identifier-list in the macro definition does not end with an ellipsis, the number of arguments (**including those arguments consisting of no preprocessing tokens**) in an invocation of a function-like macro shall equal the number of parameters in the macro definition.*