# How to remove the "*" in c++ macro args?

Tags: c++, macros

I wanna make function defines with macro, if the arg is pointer type, i will use its pointed type name, else if the arg is pure type, i will use its orignial type name.

So the question is how to remove the "*" automatically in c++ macro args?

I have tried some methods like use **VA_ARGS** or macro combinations, but i cannot find the way to solve this which seems impossible for me.

E.G:

```cpp
#define MA(arg) REMOVE_STAR(arg)##_1(arg a);

// i hope we can get this done:
MA(char) // char_1(char a);
MA(char *) // char_1(char* a);
MA(int *) // int_1(char* a);
```

---

Below is some descriptions and background for this problem, as there are so many people do not understand why i am asking for this.

Actually i know the Macro is not a good way to do programming. But in essence it's a way to reduce a lot of duplicate coding things, and as we all know, the unreal engine use macro to achieve its runtime reflection system.

So, consider such situation: i need to design a python c++ extension which will declare a lot of python methods and bind this methods to types.

1. let us refer some code from python mathmodule.c, u can see there are
   many macros for developers to reduce duplicated codes which cannot be done by Template coding.

```
#define FUNC1(funcname, func, can_overflow, docstring)                  \
    static PyObject * math_##funcname(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) { \
        return math_1(args, func, can_overflow);                            \
    }\
    PyDoc_STRVAR(math_##funcname##_doc, docstring);

#define FUNC1A(funcname, func, docstring)                               \
    static PyObject * math_##funcname(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) { \
        return math_1a(args, func);                                     \
    }\
    PyDoc_STRVAR(math_##funcname##_doc, docstring);

#define FUNC2(funcname, func, docstring) \
    static PyObject * math_##funcname(PyObject *self, PyObject *const *args, Py_ssize_t nargs) { \
        return math_2(args, nargs, func, #funcname); \
    }\
    PyDoc_STRVAR(math_##funcname##_doc, docstring);

FUNC1(acos, acos, 0,
      "acos($module, x, /)\n--\n\n"
      "Return the arc cosine (measured in radians) of x.\n\n"
      "The result is between 0 and pi.")
FUNC1(acosh, acosh, 0,
      "acosh($module, x, /)\n--\n\n"
      "Return the inverse hyperbolic cosine of x.")
FUNC1(asin, asin, 0,
      "asin($module, x, /)\n--\n\n"
      "Return the arc sine (measured in radians) of x.\n\n"
      "The result is between -pi/2 and pi/2.")
```

2. What i am gonna to achieve is: i want to declare a c++ object/pointer python wrapper type, export this wrapper to vm and add methods for this wrapper.
   I need the method name defined by the given args like:

```
#define PY_TYPE_METHOD_DEF(cls, name) cls##_##name##_DEF
#define PY_TYPE_METHOD(flags, doc, cls, name, ...) \
static PyObject * cls##_##name(PyBind<cls>* Self, __VA_ARGS__);\
static const PyMethodDef PY_TYPE_METHOD_DEF(cls, name){ \
#name, (PyCFunction) (cls##_##name), flags, doc \
}; \
static PyObject * cls##_##name(PyBind<cls>* Self, __VA_ARGS__)
```

And after this defines, i can add method defines to wrapper type like:

```
auto py_type = type_builder.
    .AddMethod(PY_TYPE_METHOD_DEF({c_type}, {method1}))  
    .AddMethod(PY_TYPE_METHOD_DEF({c_type}, {method2}))
    .AddMethod(PY_TYPE_METHOD_DEF({c_type}, {method3}))
    ...
    .Build();
```

But it comes out that if the cls is a pointer type, like int* or any other type pointer, the macro are working so bad.

So i am searching for a way to remove the "*" automatically in the macro while i know it may difficulty and even impossible.

Thks.

Comment: Or i would appreaciate  if there could be any other way to get declare such methods down.

Comment: The simple way to get this done without the macro is to simply not use the macro, but write `char_1(char a);` instead of `MA(char)`. What is the purpose of the macro?  Why do you want to write `MA(char)` ?

Comment: learn about function templates e.g. . `template<typename T> char_1(T a) { }`.  Macros really are usually one of the last thing you should try in C++

Comment: From the comments under _"i hope we can get this done"_ it look like you don't want to remove the `*` but add `a`? `#define MA(arg) char_1(arg a)`?

Comment: C++ has [`std::remove_pointer`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer) to remove the `*` off a *type*.  But AFAIK there is no way to do something similar with preprocessor macros the way you want.

Comment: "I wanna make function defines with macro" - *Why?* Avoid macros at all cost, unless they are the *only* way to solve your problem - and even then, try to see if you can solve a different problem to get to your goal, that does not involve using macros.

Comment: _"Or i would appreaciate if there could be any other way to get declare such methods down"_ - This sounds promising. Please provide a few examples of what the expected functions look like.

Comment: The questions has been updated and added with more details.

Comment: So the only reason you need to remove the `*` is to generate a unique function name based on the type?

Comment: yep, reduce programmer's mind effort to get the function name done, as well as reduce unnecessary stuffs for py method defines.

Comment: You could simply provide the `*` as separate parameter: `#define MA(argument, modifier) argument ## _1(argument modifier a)`. Beware that before C99/C++11 providing empty macro arguments was undefined: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666344/are-empty-macro-arguments-legal-in-c11 (there are workarounds for that, but you probably don't have that problem).

Comment: Yeah, this solution has come to my mind and i appreciated that we have the same thought. But it's somehow not elegant, so i am searching for a better way, while of course it will be the least and last way to get things done if we cannot find a way to trim the '*' in macro args.

Comment: A possible solution is to include [`ConstString<"...">`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68024633/2752075) somewhere in the function type, to have the same name for all functions but distinct signatures. Either in a function parameter (inconvenient, affects call signatures), or perhaps as a template parameter? `template <ConstStringParam<"...">>`